# How to show query result in group? SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now my sql query display the result as follows. 
though it is the correct result.

[image]

I prefer to have the have the result to show as follows. 
How can I do this with SQL ? I am on SQL server 2008

[image]

Comment: This is a UI operation.

Comment: IMO this is not job for SQL.

Comment: It can be done in SQL, but it's a lot easier to do in Excel.  Or SSRS. Or Crystal Reports. Or, ...

Comment: That sounds like a presentation issue, you need to handle that in your reporting tool or whatever.

Comment: Point being, SQL's job is to return the data that you request from it.  SQL's job is ***not*** to format data suitable for a report or presentation, there are many other tools for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with the commenters, better to do this elsewhere, but it's simple enough in SQL using a `CASE` statement and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN
              FROM  YourTable)
SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)) ELSE '' END, Name
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID,RN
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57559/1/0)

Comment: Thanks. Point taken on the regard that this should be the UI job.. Thank you for providing this link

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for SQL.
Any way, you can easily display it with comma separated values:

```
 ID   Names
1000  Honda, Toyota,...
1000  Honda, Toyota,...

SELECT ID, Names= 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.ID= a.ID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY ID
```